# Why are the timestamps of head blocks sometimes in the future?

Tags: timestamp

I've noticed that timestamps for new head blocks are sometimes in the future.

Specifically, if I poll `tezos-node` for a fresh block, the timestamp of the block will be in the future maybe 10% of the time, and the other 90% of the time it'll be about 5-10 seconds in the past, which seems more reasonable.

The docs for [minimal block delays](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/proof_of_stake.html#minimal-block-delays) say there is a minimal timestamp a baker can provide, so is this just a case of the baker publishing the next block after giving it a timestamp in the future?
If so, why do this when they could wait longer and include more transactions and maybe get more fees?

Comment: Make sure your server has ntp or chrony running so that your clock is accurate.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "poll `tezos-node` for a fresh block"? Do you mean that you are repeatedly reading the timestamp of the latest block in the chain?

Comment: utdrmac: I'm running a vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 LTS image in Google Cloud, and it appears to have chrony pre-configured. So I think the system time is pretty accurate.

Comment: arvidj: Yes, I'm repeatedly reading the timestamp of the latest block in the chain. When the block changes (when head gets updated), I compare the block timestamp to system time.

Comment: I am wondering if your observation that new head blocks are in the future is not realted to blocks baked by `binance` baker? By observing the logs, it seems they use a clock which is not synchronised with NTP which is ahead of about 10 seconds. But this should be considered as a bug IMHO.