# Is it possible to get (or closely approximate) the true broadcast time of the current head block?

Tags: timestamp

Is there a good way to get the true broadcast time of new head blocks? E.g. the system time of the baker that made the block would suffice.

As discussed [in this question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/why-are-the-timestamps-of-head-blocks-sometimes-in-the-future), block timestamps can vary from the apparent true broadcast time by quite a bit (maybe 15 seconds in each direction).

My current best solution is to just poll my `tezos-node` until it gives me a new block and assume the system timestamp is pretty close to the time the block was broadcast.
However, this way of including the time includes network latency, and thus is not a good solution for me - I'm actually trying to measure network latency.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi :) What do you mean by "true broadcast time"? Supposedly, the time at some actor (their system time? "true" universal time?) when a specific event occurs (when does a  "broadcast" occur? note that there is some delay between the baking of a block, and it's actual transmission from baker to network).

Comment: The system time of the baker that made the block would suffice. I realize "time" is a deep concept, and I'm not trying to get metaphysical - I just want something that approximates something NTP would generate. The context is I'm seeing huge discrepancies between the head timestamps and my own system time (like 15 seconds). I've tested using my own node and a bunch of public nodes. My system runs chrony for time synchronization.

Comment: Okay, so your concern is that there is some "lag" between the moment that blocks are baked and the moment your node picks them up. To verify, you would like to compare: 1) the timestamp of the block 2) the timestamp where the baker broadcasts the block 3) the timestamp where your node receives it?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal   I came into this thinking blocks were produced every 60 seconds give or take a second or two, but I'm seeing block times all over the place - from 45 seconds up to 2 minutes. And when I compare the head timestamps with system timestamps, I'm also seeing significant disagreements. Having the data you mentioned could help me solve this mystery. I already have 1) and 3), but I don't have 2).

Comment: If people use the baker provided by the OCaml implementation of Tezos, it seems, from what I understand that the timestamp of a block corresponds to the local time of the baker when the block was baked. It should be a good approximation for most of the bakers which are synchronised with NTP. I don't understand what you mean by `45` seconds since the tezos-node should refuse blocks which are baked too soon.